# Storing the output of my shell script in a variable

Tags: python-3.x, linux

Using the following code:

```
import subprocess
while(1==1):
    command_terminal= input('Enter the command you would like to pass: ') 
    command_terminal=command_terminal.split()
    result=subprocess.run(command_terminal, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)  
    result=result.stdout.decode('utf-8')
    print(result)
```

Basically I am trying to emulate terminal as a whole. But I am sort of failing.
Stuff like `ps -A` Doesn't give an output at all. Any help..?

Answer (score 0):

Use `subprocess.check_output`. The `encoding` argument convert the output `bytes` to `str`.

```
import subprocess

while (1 == 1):
    command_terminal = input('Enter the command you would like to pass: ')
    command_terminal = command_terminal.split()
    result = subprocess.check_output(command_terminal, encoding='utf-8')
    print(result)
```

Note that `CalledProcessError` is raise if the exit code is not zero.

Alternatively, `subprocess.run` with `capture_output=True` may be used. The output is stored in the returned `CompletedProcess.stdout` and no exception whatever the exit code is.

```
import subprocess

while (1 == 1):
    command_terminal = input('Enter the command you would like to pass: ')
    command_terminal = command_terminal.split()
    completed = subprocess.run(command_terminal, encoding='utf-8', capture_output=True)
    result = completed.stdout
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually did what you did and hosted it over on github ([https://github.com/Pythers/PyCMD/blob/master/**main**.py](https://github.com/Pythers/PyCMD/blob/master/__main__.py))

I believe your problem is that you need to set the stdout to the normal instead of subprocess.PIPE

```py
import sys
import subprocess
while 1==1:
    command_terminal= input('Enter the command you would like to pass: ')
    command_terminal=command_terminal.split()
    result=subprocess.run(command_terminal, stdout=sys.stdout)
```

Comment: If this answered your question, Kindly mark this as the answer